# Navigation Drawer на NavigationView и подпнукты

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Есть боковая выдвижная панель (меню) на NavigationView.

1. Есть ли способ сделать подпункты?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы в ландшафтном режиме эта панель не выдвигалась-задвигалась поверх активити, а сдвигала активити вправо и оставалась всегда на экране? Т.е., как сжать ативити, чтобы сбоку уместить эту панель (если это вообще возможно)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Вот так:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/section"
    android:title="@string/section_title">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_favourite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/favourite"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_downloaded"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/downloaded"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

2) Делаешь отдельные лейауты для ландшафта и портрета, в портретном с `DrawerLayout`, в ландшафтном без.

**Обновление**

1. Ну такого `NavigationView` не умеет и что бы научить полагаю придется знатно заморочиться, проще тогда `ExpandableListView` туда и вставить.
2. А кто Вам `NavigationView` то в ландшафте говорит не использовать, я только `Navigation Drawer` говорил не использовать, ну то есть `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: 1) Это понятно, но я имел ввиду аналог ExpandableListView (по типу http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/android-expandable-listview.jpg)